# How can I conditionally select and then mutate columns of a DataFrame?

Tags: julia

I'm looking for `mutate_if()` from R's dplyr. For example, how could I select the `Int64` columns and convert them to Float?

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = [72, 38, 54],
               B = [1, 2, 3],
               C = ["red", "blue", "green"])
# convert integer columns to decimal columns without selecting them by name
df
```

Comment: It looks like you can do this with the [`@linq` macro from the `DataFramesMeta` package](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFramesMeta.jl#linq-macro). I just stumbled across this, so no fully-baked answer, but if I figure something out I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is. The code converts columns with any integer number types (such as `Int64`, `Int32`) to a `Float64`.

```
for col in findall(x -> x <:Integer, eltypes(df))
   df[!, col] = Float64.(df2[!, col])
end
```

Comment: What does the exclamation mark by itself in square brackets mean?

Comment: `DataFrame`s are indexed by two dimensions (row and column), `!` selects all rows. This is a new, recently release API. Currently `df[col] ` would work but triggers a depracation warning.